# Predicting multiple target variables

Tags: database, variables, regression, prediction, target

Hello please I am new to making predictions of multiple targets, but not sure how to go about it. So i have a total of 12 columns and 3 out of them are my target variables, what are the possible models for this kind of problem. I have been doing single target predictions but not sure how to go about this one. below is sample of the table, my targets are the three coloured columns [sample_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTXXy.png) picth, yaw and degree. Is there a model for this kind of situation or I have to predict one after the other.
my motive is to train and predict the three targets using fresh data.

Comment: What's your framework? Sklearn supports multioutput (i.e. a vector of targets) natively for the majority of its models, and provides `sklearn.multioutput.MultiOutputRegressor()` wrapper for the others.

Comment: thank you @dx2-66, I used Multioutputregressor. I think it did what I expected.